# ActiveMQ true P2P network of brokers

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm looking for a way to have a true P2P network of brokers. Ideally, I'd like to have a true p2p network of broker clusters. For example, I have datacenter A, B, C. Each datacenter has one highly available cluster of brokers. I don't need to load balance in a datacenter, I just need HA at a datacenter. How can I create a P2P network of these HA clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I got the answer here: http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.4/clustering/index.html, the in the article Combining Fault Tolerance with Load Balancing. It looks like these guys consult on ActiveMQ and have a product called Fuse Message Broker that is just a rebranded ActiveMQ.

Comment: its the other way around. activemq is the open source version of fuse message broker. the guys over at fusesource startet the project.